# Managing a queue with multiple elements

Tags: jquery, queue

I need an event to start and then stop/clear a queue of animations/actions for multiple elements. I created this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/mzdoherty/bVuVs/1/)  based off this [example](http://tobymackenzie.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/animation-queue-management-for-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a good starting point:

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}

#one {
    background:green;
}

#two {
    background: red;
}
```

​
**HTML**

```
<button id="startQueue">Go</button>
<button id="clearQueue">Clear</button>

<div id="one" class="queueItem"></div>
<div id="two" class="queueItem"></div>​
```

**JS**

```
// Global Queue Array //
var queue = [];

// Start Queue //
$('#startQueue').bind('click', function(e){
    // Go through Each Element and Fade Out //
    $('.queueItem').each(function(i, $el){
        // Don't Delay First Element//
        if (i==0) {
            queue.push($(this).fadeOut(5000));
        } else {
            queue.push($(this).delay(5000*i).fadeOut(5000));
        }        
    });
});

// Stop / Clear Queue //
$('#clearQueue').bind('click', function(e){
    $.each(queue, function(i, $el){
        // Stop Animation and Reset Elements //
        $el.stop(true, true).css({
            display: 'block',
            opacity: '1'
        });

        // Clear Queue Array //
        queue = [];
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/D7jKJ/)**

Good Luck!